# Does an identity exist for distributing the inverse for a product including nonsquare matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

For example, if $A$ and $B$ are invertible square matrices, we can write $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A^{-1}$.

Now, consider $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $C$ is an $n \times m$ matrix. If $A$ is invertible, does an identity exist for distributing the inverse inside parenthesis of a product of matrices including a nonsquare matrix such as $C$?

For example, if $(C^T A C)^{-1}$ exists, does some identity exist for $(C^T A C)^{-1}$?

Comment: It requires the general Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a matrix, and that too only in certain cases. Basically, if $C$ is non-square, the only way to work with $C$ is using the notion of inverse for a non-square matrix , which extends the usual notion of an inverse. Indeed, the MP pseudoinverse must come into play, as the answer below indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common generalization of an inverse to a non-square matrix $A$ is a [Moore–Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) $A^+$. An equality $(AB)^+=B^+A^+$ [holds in special cases, but not in general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Products).

Comment: I don't see how this can be useful for deriving an identity. The pseudoinverse is not equal to the inverse.

Comment: @Ralff I don’t understand. When a matrix $A$ is invertible, its pseudoinverse is its inverse, see, for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Basic_properties). When $A$ is not invertible, its inverse does not exists.